# Waiting for kafka consumer to complete its operations

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

***Use case***: I have a use case where the client send a request to an microservice endpoint (the producer) which does some operations and produce a message to the kafka to be consumed by a consumer which stores some data into his own database. Immediately after this, the client send another request to the consumer microservice to get latest updates (which should include data stored previously).

But the problem is that the client is sending the second request without waiting for consumer to finish storing data (for the first request).

***Question***: how should I handle it? Can somehow wait for consumer to finish storing data?

***What I tried***: I tried to add thread.sleep into producer endpoint, but I don't like that solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Kafka, or any other queues/streaming-system are used in case of asynchronous communication and eventual consistency should be ok in that particular case....

May i know the use case to better comment on it ?

Thread.sleep is not a good solution for sure... What  if consumers are stuck due to certain reasons, in that case your thread.sleep solution will not work

Comment: You can initiate read request from the consumer thread itself or by triggering anothe r event that marks the completion of the event.

Comment: @SahilGupta how can I initiate a read request from the consumer to the client?

Comment: if it's another system then you can't unless integration point is available .. But you can go with another approach i mentioned...

Comment: Do let me know if it helped.. i will add the same as an answer then

Comment: So, you are proposing that the consumer should set a flag to mark event completion? I don't think that will work because that flag should be cleared in the beginning of the event (when consumer consumes the message from the producer), but we don't know when this happens.

Comment: Send an event in another topic that can represent the completion of consumption and in the consumer of that event you can do whatever is required...

Comment: But the client still doesn't know WHEN to request for updates (after the consumer completes its operation)

Comment: Kafka doesn't replace traditional synchronous request-response... If you have a requesting client that is _not a Kafka consumer itself_, then you're locked into polling for status or having your "microservice" return an "accepted" message on the producer ack. For more details, research Distributed sagas and CQRS

Comment: I am having same question did you resolved it ? if yes then how ? I am new to Kafka :)